# How to set a global variable to hold path to resource files?

Tags: robotframework

It would be nice to use a variable when importing resources to test cases. Right now I import them like this:

```
Resource     ${EXECDIR}/resources/RandomPage.resource
```

I would like to import them like this:

```
Resource     ${RESOURCES}/RandomPage.resource
```

And there is a `Set Global Variable` keyword, which could be used to set the `${RESOURCES}`, but I can't decide where to put it, Setups do not seem a good place.
Where is a good practice to initialize this variable?

Comment: Add the base directory RESOURCES into your pythonpath and you can use relative includes like Randompage.resource.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as command line argument:

```
robot -v ${RESOURCES}:<value> <rest of the arguments>
```

But what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

First, using the `Variables` section as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ${RESOURCE}

*** Variables ***
${RESOURCE}    path/to/resource/file
```

Second, you can create a variables.py file and reference it in the `Settings` section as follows

**variables.py**

```
RESOURCE = 'path/to/resource/file'
```

**test_suite.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource     ${RESOURCE}
Variables    /path/to/variable.py
```

Comment: You can use this approach and combine it with the command line as suggested by @JaPyR to give yourself the flexibility of different sets of resources for different execution environments.

Comment: @Dday, In this case you can also use different sets of variables using the command line option `--variables path/to/variables.py` to use different execution environments